# PS: How can i change a value of an item of an array when selected with 'Where-Object'?

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell, for-loop, where-clause

I have a array of objects like this:

```
$arr1 = 1..40 |% {[pscustomobject]@{value=0;type="D";used=$false}}

[.. do something ..]

PS C:\Windows\system32> $arr1
                    value type                                                   used
                    ----- ----                                                   ----
                        1 H                                                      True
                        2 H                                                      True
                        3 H                                                      True
                        4 H                                                      True
                        5 H                                                      True
                        6 H                                                      True
                        7 H                                                      True
                        8 H                                                      True
                        9 H                                                      True
                       10 H                                                      True
                       11 H                                                     False
                       12 H                                                     False
                       13 H                                                     False
                        1 D                                                     False
                        2 D                                                     False
```

[...]

With `Where-Object` I want to select a specific Object in my Array:

```
$arr1 | ? {$_.value -eq $newc.value -and $_.type -eq $newc.type}


                    value type                                                   used
                    ----- ----                                                   ----
                        6 C                                                      True
```

The selection with the `"`?`"` workes well as you can see, but now I want to set the `$used` Flag for this specific Object to `$false`.

How can I do this? I have the Problem that I don't know the position in the array where my `"?-Clause"` did match. (With "position" I mean the `$arr1[POSITION]`. I don't know what number the item has in my array)

I think it would work if I would use an for-loop and would check every `$arr1[$i]` if my conditions match. But I think there must be an more elegant way for this? Or do I really need the for-loop to check every single item in my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$toChange = $arr1 | ? {($_.value -eq $newc.value) -and ($_.type -eq $newc.type)}
$toChange | % { $_.used = $false }
```

Use your `Where-Object` query to grab a list of items to change, and then make the change by iterating over them using the `Foreach-Object` or `%`

Or you could do it in one line:

```
$arr1 | ? {($_.value -eq $newc.value) -and ($_.type -eq $newc.type)} | % { $_.used = $false }
```